# Redhat & GUI/GNOME Struggle?

Tags: rhel, gnome, gui, gdm, runlevel

We have in our Company SysAdmin so damm stupied and lazy.
Everytime I ask him for a Redhat Virtual Machine(VM),He just deploy a ready template with GUI and lot of package,a lot I think he just install every damm RPM package in redhat.

Beside security issue and need of patch which I never ever saw him doing it.
I was hoping to conserve resources(Memory/Disk).
As most of you know tha redhat use GNOME Desktop Envirement.

**My Question** here can I disable/enable Gnome whenever needed without system down(No another reason for SysAdmin to hate me).

Here what I found on the internt

**First Method**

yum groupremove gnome-desktop : Quit not option to remove GUI completly since we need it for some mission(couple of times per year).

**Second Method**

Edit /etc/inittab file to replace runlevel from 5(multiuser with GUI) to 3 (multiuser without GUI).Although the file contain instruction to diffrent manaer of doing it but I suppose it the same.Well, first it didn't work I still get GUI whenver I connected with XRDP,second it involve downtime for rebooting.

**Third Method**

Stop GNOME Desktop Manager(gdm) service,still the damm GUI.

**Fourth Method**

telinit 3 or init 3 to change runlevels , I even don't what the result.It damm close all SSH session VM is still up (ftp working).Now I have to ask SysAdmin for help that mean work he will really hate me , thanks god it was lab VM or I am dead for sure.

**Dead End**

So I am at Deadend,anyone encountred this 
issue,It will be really nice if redhat folks share their experience.

**Last Idea**

One last thing , I thought to remove gnome and install LXDE is redhat would support that.

*Thank You.*

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to use GUI but with minimal packages.

This is the action plan.

**if [access system through ssh == yes]; then**

1. tell your sysadmin to *please* create a new base template using just the
   minimal packages. RHEL gives this option at the time of installation. Also, tell him that you do not bother him with the installation of any new packages.
2. when you want gui:

   a. install xorg-x11-xauth

   b. install gui app. (ex: firefox)

   c. ssh -X root@your-server and launch "firefox&"
3. if step 1 not at all possible (even after using *please* & offering a free beer), remove all the gnome packages & other rpms you hate. Then apply step 2

**else**

if you are accessing it directly with no ssh, then I do not think you have a choice here. Changing the runlevel and keeping the gnome/lxde packages is the only option.

Comment: I am in  the "IF" accessing the server only through SSH,but when I test locally in vmware Workstation I created RHLE 7.2 VM with min install.I get error starting GUI apps like jconsole " libXrender.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" and firefox "Error: cannot open display: localhost:10.0". It seem that some GUI apps need libraries installed with GNOME.